# sql server: how to return the latest sales data by employee

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL noob here. I'm kind of beat.

So I have a list of data of sales employees like this

```
Employee Name|  Sales Timestamp  | Item Sold
             ---------------------
Jackie  Chan |  07/11/2014       | TV
Jessica Alba |  08/01/2014       | Sofa
Jessica Alba |  07/25/2014       | Stereo System
Will Ferrell |  06/30/2014       | Sofa
Will Ferrell |  07/15/2014       | TV
```

I want to return employee, the latest date they sold something, and the item sold.

I have tried

```
 Select [Employee Name], MAX[Sales Timestamp], [ITEM SOLD]
FROM Sales
GROUP BY [Employee Name], [ITEM SOLD]
```

but that gives me each employee's latest sales of ANY items, whereas I just want the latest item they sold.

Please help!

Comment: It that all you have in your table? do you have Id field? You can filter using Where statement and sort by Sales Timestamp and get first record but i don't know how reliable your timespamp column is.

Comment: Hi vgSefa,  I do have an employee id column. And the Timestamp is reliable, just did not type out the hour, min and seconds.

Comment: You don't have any information that can give you lastest sale of that employee. It's just not stored. As i said you can order by date and get first item, that will give you one of the sales made at closest day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH SalesCTE AS
(
    SELECT [Employee Name],
           [Sales Timestamp],
           [ITEM SOLD],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Employee Name] ORDER BY [Sales Timestamp] DESC) AS rn
    FROM   Sales
)
SELECT [Employee Name],
       [Sales Timestamp],
       [ITEM SOLD]
FROM   SalesCTE
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bed7e/2/0):

```
SELECT s.[Employee Name], s.[Sales Timestamp], s.[ITEM SOLD]
FROM 
(
  Select [Employee Name] AS emp,  MAX([Sales Timestamp]) AS ts
  FROM Sales 
  GROUP BY [Employee Name]
) AS ss
INNER JOIN Sales s ON ss.emp = s.[Employee Name] AND ss.ts = s.[Sales Timestamp]
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the analytic functions for this one:

```
WITH RankByDate AS (
  SELECT
    EmployeeName,
    SalesTimestamp,
    ItemSold,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY EmployeeName
      ORDER BY Salestimestamp DESC
    ) AS TRank
  FROM Sales
)
SELECT * FROM RankByDate
```

If the salesperson sold more than one item on the latest date, this query differs from the others in that it will only show one of the items. It's unclear from the sample data what should happen in this scenario. If you want to show all items sold on the latest date, replace `ROW_NUMBER()` with `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()`.